# Does every Android phone come with a "Ringtones" directory?

Tags: android, file

Very simple question. I am wondering if **every** Android device comes, by default, with the *Ringtones* directory, either in the internal or in the external storage.

Plus, if the answer is positive, I would like to know if that folder's name gets **localized** or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Ringtones is a Standard directory in Android [DIRECTORY_RINGTONES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)
You can access it as follows:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)
```

However, you should use [RingtoneManager](http://veloper.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) because it will give you ringtones from all directories.
e.g.

```
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
```

Comment: I could've figured it out myself, it's Monday morning and I'm still dazed :) FYI, I won't be using the directory for "standard" purposes.